# How to upload a file using Node JS function in Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, serverless

I am trying to create an Azure function that handles file upload. I have tried different options (trying to read from request directly or using formidable).

For both these cases I am getting following error when the function is executed.

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.UploadFile. mscorlib: TypeError: req.on is not a function  
    at IncomingForm.parse (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:117:6)  
    at module.exports (D:\home\site\wwwroot\UploadFile\index.js:5:10)  
    at D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\1.0.11702\bin\azurefunctions\functions.js:106:24.
```

The function code is as below

```
var formidable = require("formidable");  

module.exports = function (context, request) {  
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');      
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();  
    form.parse(request, function (err, fields, files) {  
        context.res = { body : "uploaded"};  
    });  
    context.done();  
};
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you try something like:

`const buffers = [];
request.on('data', (data) => { buffers.push(data); });
 request.on('end',  () => {
    context.res = { body : "uploaded"}; 
   context.done();
});`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am getting the same error message with this code. Is it likely that in Azure framework the request object is not implementing right set of interfaces?

Comment: Can you please try logging `request` object to see if it has the same interface as `express.js` or some other frameworks?

Comment: When I did context.log(request), all I got was request [object Object] in the logs. Is there any other way to find out interfaces?

Comment: You can `JSON.stringify()` it or `util.inspect()` it.

Comment: Both the methods just print string representation without class information. Thanks for your continued help.

Answer (score 6):

I got it to work with following. Request object is neither a Stream nor an EventEmitter in Azure functions (and in AWS lambda too). It just has body and headers populated. I took help from https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-multipart. I had to tune it for Azure functions

```
var multipart = require("parse-multipart");

module.exports = function (context, request) {  
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.'); 
    // encode body to base64 string
    var bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(request.body);
    // get boundary for multipart data e.g. ------WebKitFormBoundaryDtbT5UpPj83kllfw
    var boundary = multipart.getBoundary(request.headers['content-type']);
    // parse the body
    var parts = multipart.Parse(bodyBuffer, boundary);
    context.res = { body : { name : parts[0].filename, type: parts[0].type, data: parts[0].data.length}}; 
    context.done();  
};
```

This seems to work better with Azure Function 2.x runtime (beta). I have updated the code. I have tested this with PDF, JPG, PNG and XLSX.

Comment: the above code works if there is the only file, but fails if we have other fields along with a file.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you're reading binary data, as mentioned here —
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#binding-datatype-property

> For languages that are dynamically typed such as JavaScript, use the `dataType` property in the **function.json** file. For example, to read the content of an HTTP request in binary format, set `dataType` to `binary`:
>
> ```
> {
>    "type": "httpTrigger",
>    "name": "req",
>    "direction": "in",
>    "dataType": "binary"
> }
> ```
>
> Other options for dataType are `stream` and `string`.

Comment: I tried binary and stream. It did not work. From following post it seems that request is not a stream in Azure hence events are not working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43614581/deploying-a-node-app-on-azure-functions