# upload file from angular app to an azure function and then persist to blob storage

Tags: node.js, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I want to upload an image to an azure function and there persist it to azure blob storage but I cannot find any good articles about how to do this.

SOme posts say it is not possible to do this as node azure functions have problems with multipart.

I don't want my client app to know what storage mechanism is used so I don't want to use `azure-storage-node` client library because we will be locked into using.

I've tried this code:

```
const upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() });

module.exports = function(context: Context, req: any) {
  upload.any()(req, {} as any, function(err: any) {
    context.log('here we are');
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    context.log(req.body);
    context.log(req);
    console.log(req.file);
    context.log(req.files);
    context.done(undefined, context);
  });
```

But req.files is undefined and I had to set the content type to `application/octet-stream` or else I got `req.pipe is not a function`.

How can I get the `req.files` into azure storage from an azure function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [a sample GIT project](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-js) which uses the [@azure/storage-blob SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob) to add blobs into Azure.  It sounds like you don't want to use an SDK, so you could look at the SDK source and take the code you need.

Comment: Also see this SO question's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526133/how-to-upload-a-file-using-node-js-function-in-azure